# How do I create a function object which modifies its arguments?

Tags: c++, boost, googlemock

I'd like to replace `SomeFunction` and `SetArg` with something more generic from `boost`.
It looks like something that can be done with `bind` in combination with `lambda`, but I don't know how.

This code is very simple but the reason I'd like to replace it is because I need one for `2` and `3` etc arguments.

```
template<class T>
struct SomeFunction
{
    T value;
    SomeFunction(T s)
        : value(s) {}

    void operator()(T& s)
    {
        s = value;
    }
};

template<class T>
SomeFunction<T> SetArg(T value)
{
    return SomeFunction<T>(value);
}
```

The requirements:

- I want a function which returns a function object.
- When I call this function object, the parameters are passed by reference.
- The function modifies the objects passed in by reference by setting them to pre-set values.
- In the code above the pre-set values are passed in by value in the `ctor`, but any other way is also fine.

The following code demonstrates the usage:

```
void main()
{
    std::string t;
    SetArg(std::string("hello"))(t);
    assert(t == "hello");
}
```

Some context:

I want to test the client code of class `Foo`. So I want to replace the implementation of `func1` with my own, but in a flexible way.

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual void func1(std::string& s)
    {
    }
};

struct MockFoo : public Foo {
    MOCK_METHOD1(func1, void(std::string&));
};

void ExampleTestCase::example()
{
  MockFoo f;
  std::string s;

  EXPECT_CALL(f, func1(_))
      .WillOnce(Invoke(SetArg(std::string("hello"))));

  f.func1(s);

  CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(std::string("hello"), s);
}
```

Invoke takes a function or function object. Inside the new implementation of `func1` it calls the function object returned by `SetArg` and sets its argument to the string `"hello"`.

Invoke is part of gmock/gtest but `SetArg` is not.

Comment: Quick remark: `SetArg` should take its argument by reference-to-const or by rvalue reference. I also don't see what you want to do. Can you elaborate more without using macros from some framework?

Comment: In phoenix, I believe something like `ref(s) = arg1` and `arg1 = <x>` are what you are looking for.

Comment: Would a simple generalization of `SomeFunction` with variadic templates suffice?

Comment: @pmr I added a simple main function so you don't need to worry about the gmock/gtest/cppunit stuff.

Comment: @kerrek SB Yes! What would that look like?

Comment: @Eddy: Something like `template <typename ...Args> SomeFunction<Args...> SetArg(const Args &... args) { return SomeFunction<Args...>(args...); }`. I'm a bit confused that your template class doesn't make any use of the template parameter, though.

Comment: After the edit I think that `std::tuple` and `std::tie` could work out well for this.

Comment: @pmr: A `tuple` certainly comes to mind, but I'm confused because I don't see how the template parameters are relevant in the OP's class definition.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, I feel that OP needs to flesh out his requirements more to make this question answerable.

Comment: @pmr I tried to make the requirements more clear. Who's the OP? I'm the EP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. The `operator()` of setter would probably
require some tweaking as we are not really benefiting from the
possible move semantics here, but I can't figure that out right now.

Also note that this makes heavy use of C++11 features which might not
be available to you.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

// set arbitrary values to 
template<typename... Args>
struct setter {
  // needed because we cannot use initializer lists as they require assignment
  setter(const std::tuple<Args&...>& t) : t(t) {}
  std::tuple<Args...> t;

  // again a template to trigger deduction again
  template<typename... Args2>
  void operator()(Args2&&... args) {
    t = std::make_tuple(args...);
  }
};

template<typename... Args>
setter<Args&...> create_setter(Args&... args) {
  return setter<Args&...>(std::tie(args...));
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  long l = 1;
  std::string foo = "foo";

  auto s = create_setter(i, l, foo);

  s(23, 42, "bar");
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  std::cout << l << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neat! Which compiler did you use?

Comment: @EddyPronk gcc 4.6 Be aware: This code still needs a lot of tweaking and a few `static_asserts` for full produciton value.